# Generating (pseudo) random numbers from a log file (eg. /var/log/maillog)

Tags: cryptography, random-number-generator

First: I really know that a true random number generator should have real random input, like something that is impossible to predict.

Now, consider this: A busy mail-server can generate tens of lines per second in /var/log/maillog (Postfix). Let's say I tail the last 500 lines in the log file and calculate the SHA512 message digest. That would give me 512 bits (64 bytes) of pretty random data.  Assuming of course that I am the only one who has access to the log file, and that nobody knows that I'm doing this. I can do this every minute and get 512 pretty random bits every minute. That in turn can be used to encrypt something secret-ish.

A real cryptologist would of course say that this is bad and that I should not do it (trust the randomness of my generator), but I'm still curios. How hard would it be to predict my "random" data without access to the server?

Of course, it doesn't need to be a log file. It could be a tap on an ethernet interface for example. A busy 10 Gig router would yield a lot of data. Not random by itself, but ran through SHA message digest, wouldn't it be more or less impossible to predict the output without the exact input?

As for a pseudo random generator, I think it would work. But would it be better than a known PRNG?

Comment: "That would give me 512 bits (64 bytes) of pretty random data." - 64 bytes of random data hasn't been enough to secure encryption for a very long time.  We are getting to the point where 2048 bit keys aren't even enough (RSA).  Which is the reason, good pseudo-random generators, use multiple sources of randomness. Let alone the fact, the minute your mail-server service stops working, your source of randomness is now static.

Answer (score 0):

> and that nobody knows that I'm doing this.

This goes against Kerckhoff's principle. In general we assume that an adversary knows the schemes in use. It takes only one compromised person / system to show this after all.

> How hard would it be to predict my "random" data without access to the server?

Relatively easy, as an adversary would probably have a method to insert his own log entries by attacking the system.

> Of course, it doesn't need to be a log file. It could be a tap on an ethernet interface for example. A busy 10 Gig router would yield a lot of data.

This kind of data is generally already used by the system's RNG. Routers are generally not used as it is dangerous to rely on external devices / services.

> Not random by itself, but ran through SHA message digest, wouldn't it be more or less impossible to predict the output without the exact input?

No. Although it is impossible to invert a hash function a cryptographic hash doesn't do anything to disallow an adversary to guess the input.

Generally the seeding procedure of a random number generator already performs some kind of hashing on new input. It would still make sense to hash it yourself first, if just to reduce the I/O.

> As for a pseudo random generator, I think it would work. But would it be better than a known PRNG?

Your method requires way too much entropy to generate good random numbers. A good PRNG can run almost forever on just 128-256 bits of *fully random* entropy.

You can use it to *extract* (compress) entropy from a large input, which you then can use to add additional seed to the system's random number generator.

Generally you don't need it; just use the system random, which will use better thought out schemes to gather entropy.